# RestKit post request parameter MIMEType

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm working on an iOS app that was implement in RestKit .10 and am updating it to .20. One of the post requests the app makes has a block of data as a parameter. Previously, the app encoded this use RKParam setData:MIMEType:forParam; I'm looking for the .20 version of this for adding a parameter to a NSMutableDictionary parameter.

Old code:

```
  NSString *logString; // loaded up elsewhere

  NSData *textFileContentsData = [logString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  RKParams *params = [RKParams params];

  [params setData: textFileContentsData MIMEType:@"text/plain" forParam:@"log_file"];
```

New code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


[parameters setObject:???? forKey:@"log_file"];  // not sure how to get string here.
```

I have tried putting the textFileContentsData NSData object in for ???? but the data arrives in binary, which is not what is required. I need to figure out how to retain the text/plain MIMEType.

TIA

Janene

Comment: What is the server expecting to receive?

Comment: @Wain the server expects a parameter with MIMEType text/plain. The text is a large amount of information extracted from a log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I wouldn't use RestKit for this as there is no mapping going on, I'd use AFNetworking instead (vehicular is included in RestKit so you already have full access).

Using RestKit, you would use the object manager to create a request to send, something like:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
        [objectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:nil
                                               method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                 path:@"..."
                                           parameters:nil
                            constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                                [formData appendPartWithFormData:...
                                                            name:@"..."];

        }];
```

Then you could use `RKObjectRequestOperation` to process the request. But I'm not convinced this is exactly what you need if you just want to set the mime type (just a header) and the post data, both of which can be done directly on `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Comment: Thanks, Wain. Unfortunately, RestKit is not optional for this app, but I'll look into this approach, thanks!

Comment: I'm not saying to remove RestKit, just to be selective where using it and using more appropriate APIs...